# Serialize DataTable into JSON Object in C# Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am Developing WEB API using ASP.NET. I have little bit trouble while serializing the datatable. When I serialize the DataTable it serialized as a Json String. But I need either JSON Object or JSON ARRAY.

My code

```
[ActionName("EMPID")]
public System.Collections.IEnumerable Get()
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
    string connString = ConfigurationManager
                          .ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"]
                          .ConnectionString;

    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString;
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    string query = "select EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,SALARY from Employee ";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dataTable);

    var JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);
    return JSONString;
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
}
```

But it returns as JSON String. I need as a JSON Object.

Example

> "[{\"EMPLOYEE_ID\":2,\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Michael\",\"SALARY\":800000},{\"EMPLOYEE_ID\":3,\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Roy\",\"SALARY\":700000},{\"EMPLOYEE_ID\":4,\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Tom\",\"SALARY\":600000},{\"EMPLOYEE_ID\":5,\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Jerry\",\"SALARY\":650000},{\"EMPLOYEE_ID\":6,\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Philip\",\"SALARY\":7500000},{\"EMPLOYEE_ID\":7,\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Sachin\",\"SALARY\":1100000},{\"EMPLOYEE_ID\":8,\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Anshu\",\"SALARY\":1200000},{\"EMPLOYEE_ID\":9,\"FIRST_NAME\":\"Ravish\",\"SALARY\":1000000}]"

But I need to Serialize as Object Like,

> {"name":"Manas","gender":"Male","birthday":"1987-8-8"}

I am little bit confused with JSON Serialization & Deserialization.

Comment: You're going to want to iterate over your data table and create a list of Employee objects based on the datatable rows. Then you can convert that list of Employee objects into JSON in the way you are expecting.

Comment: Change the Function Type to" IHttpActionResult "

"Return OK(dataTable);"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Stop working with DataTable. They're a poor abstraction for the data. Use strongly typed objects. [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) is handy for this. It is a micro-ORM that works with any ADO.NET data provider. You provide the query, and it will map the results of the query to a strongly typed object (a class). Dapper is available [on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper).

2) Your action method shouldn't return an `IEnumerable`. It should return an `IEnumerable<T>`

3) You should let the framework handle converting your objects to JSON, don't do it yourself. There's no need to involve JSON.NET. If you return your object from your action method, the framework will convert it to JSON for you.

4) You are not using the [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) pattern correctly on your disposable objects (SqlConnection). They need to be wrapped in a `using` statement or disposed of in a `finally` block.

5) You have two SqlConnection's and only need one.

6) You should utilize the repository pattern instead of doing data access directly in your controller. Follow separation of concerns, have a separate class responsible for this.

Data Repository

```
using Dapper; //add this to your using statements

public class EmployeeRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public EmployeeRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        string query = "select EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, SALARY from Employee";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            // Query is an extension method from Dapper
            List<Employee> employees = connection.Query<Employee>(query).AsList();
            return employees;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class EmployeeController
{
    private readonly EmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeController()
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager
                                .ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"]
                                .ConnectionString;

        _employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository(connString);
    }

    [ActionName("EMPID")] //why does this say EMPID?
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
    {            
        List<Employee> employees = _employeeRepository.GetAllEmployees();
        return employees;      
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

---

If you didn't want to use Dapper, you can manually processes the results of your command:

```
var employees = new List<Employee>();

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("select EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, SALARY from Employee", connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.EmployeeId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("EMPLOYEE_ID"));
            employee.FirstName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FIRST_NAME"));
            employee.Salary = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("SALARY"));
            employees.Add(employee);
        }
    }
}

return employees;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. That's what I needed. Then I have mentioned this  [ActionName("EMPID")] for URL Controller. 

But I need to know How Dapper is best than native method.?

Comment: @Ganeshgm7 My point is that "EMPID" makes no sense if your query has nothing to do with employees ID's. The action name should be "employees" which would make much more sense. As for how Dapper is better, it keeps you from needing to write tedious repetitive code to turn the results of SQL queries into objects.

Comment: Dapper is well suited for me. But I need to know how to do it without dapper, just for an educational purpose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ganeshgm7 You would create a SQL command, associate it with the connection, execute the query into a SqlDataReader, then loop through the results on the SqlDataReader creating a new object for each iteration (populating its properties from the SqlDataReader) and adding it to a collection declared outside of your loop.

Comment: @Ganeshgm7 I've added an example to my answer of how you can do it without Dapper.

Comment: Thank you. Dapper is suited for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159051/discussion-between-ganeshgm7-and-mason).